# Freestyle cropping of images

Tags: android

Im new to android. Searched a lot and can't find any possible solution for cropping an image by hand at any shape and saving it. Pls help.

Also with my little knowledge, i got an idea(dont know if it work).

It is:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // finger moves on the screen

**Here code for getting X & Y positions and dynamically cropping side by side.**

}
```

Pls help...

Comment: Is this what you have tried? Do you know how to crop image in android ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the default cropping functionality of android ?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use default android Crop functionality as below:

```
private void imageCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Declare constant variable in your activity at top:

```
final int PIC_CROP = 1;
```

And in onActivity result method, writ following code:

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        if (data != null) {
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

            imgView.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

This how you can do it. 
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks grishu. Is this for cropping the image irregularly?

Comment: This code is used to simply crop the image which is supported by android for croping image. What you mean by cropping image irregularly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using android's default cropping functionality.

```
private void performCrop(Uri uri) {
    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent,
                request_code); // int value
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // device doesn't support cropping
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // something went wrong
    }
}
```

Then get the image through onActivityResult

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Comment: For cropping irregularly?

Comment: what do you mean irregularly? 

anyway, this lets you crop an image.. a rectangle or a square.. any size..

Comment: Other than the usual square or rectangle, any irregular shape that we draw by hand.